# Ожидание в с++/cli winforms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Как осуществить ожидания в с++/cli? Например мне нужно, что бы второй label запускался через 5 секунд после первого. Как это сделать? Если делать через `Sleep()` получается не корректно.

```
this->label1->Visible = true;
Sleep(10000);
this->label2->Visible = true;
```

Если сделать вот так, тогда программа просто остановится (ее не будет видно) и через 10 секунд только появится.

Comment: Покажите код, как вы пытались сделать.

Comment: Такая же штука с другими процессами, например `Beep(404,10000)`, сначало будет звук, а через 10 секунд появится  сама программа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Показанный код работает в gui-потоке. Отрисовка формы, что неудивительно, происходит в этом же потоке. То есть даётся команда показать первый лейбл, потом поток засыпает, потом даётся команда показать второй лейбл, после чего метод завершается и управление наконец-то получает метод обработки оконных сообщений, который выполнит ранее полученные команды - то есть покажет лейблы.

Что можно предпринять?

1. Переходите на C#. Язык C++/CLI предназначен для одной цели: использоваться в качестве "клея" между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом. Писать полноценные приложения на нём сродни самоубийству. Обратите внимание: в Visual Studio даже нет шаблона проекта Windows Forms для C++/CLI.
2. Простейшее решение - использовать [Application::DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.100).aspx). Однако, его применение чревато багами и не рекомендуется. В частности, хоть первый лейбл и отрисуется сразу, но потом форма замёрзнет, пока поток спит. См. ответы в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181777/5045688) теме (и [эту](https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/) статью).

   ```
   this->label1->Visible = true;
   Application::DoEvents();
   Threading::Thread::Sleep(5000);
   this->label2->Visible = true;
   ```
3. Можно использовать выполнение длительной операции в другом потоке.

   ```
   this->label1->Visible = true;               
   Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::InvokeThread));
   thread->Start();

   private: void InvokeThread() {
       Thread::Sleep(5000);
       this->label2->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &MyForm::ShowLabel));
   }

   private: void ShowLabel() {
       this->label2->Visible = true;
   }
   ```

   Что тут происходит? Показывается первый лейбл и запускается поток. Этот поток сперва спит, потом показывает второй лейбл. Обратите внимание, что обращение к контролам формы возможно только из того же потока, в котором они созданы. А из другого потока нужно использовать [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).

   Синтаксис C++/CLI чудовищен! Приходится на ровном месте делать лишние методы. Поэтому ещё раз советую переходить на C# (там возможны анонимные делегаты и лямбды).
4. Используем таймер. Кидаем из тулбокса на форму таймер. Задаём в его свойствах нужное значение `Interval` (по умолчанию там 100 миллисекунд). Дважды кликаем по нему - создастся обработчик события `Tick`. В этом событии пишем:

   ```
   private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
       this->label2->Visible = true;
       timer1->Stop();
   }
   ```

   Думаю тут всё понятно: показывается второй ярлык и останавливается таймер. Этот метод выполняется в потоке gui, поэтому `Invoke` не нужен.
   Код, показывающий первый ярлык и запускающий таймер:

   ```
   this->label1->Visible = true;
   timer1->Start();
   ```

   Обратите внимание, `Thread::Sleep` тут не нужен!
5. А теперь я пособлазняю возможностями шарпа.

   ```
   label1.Visible = true;
   await Task.Delay(5000);
   label2.Visible = true;
   ```

   Это весь код, нужный для выполнения задачи!

Comment: спасибо. А с# от с++ сильно отличается? Все таки стоит на него переходить? Или все таки QT начать учитть?

Comment: или вообще на java перейти?

Comment: @OlegSkip - Синтаксис несколько отличается, но он намного проще, в результате быстро учится. К тому же Visual Studio половину кода будет дописывать за вас сама. А главное - .NET Framework тот же, учить новое не придётся. / QT - придётся забыть всё, связанное с управляемым (managed) кодом. Java - мало применяется для разработки для декстопа. Опять же, придётся многое учить заново. Итого: надо попробовать все три языка/технологии и выбрать наиболее понравившуюся.

Comment: ээх, сложная штука программирование. даже язык выбрать не могу)

Comment: думаю сейчас сфокусируюсь на QT и java, спасибо за ответы, реально они мне очень помогли