# Как сделать плавное появление элемента?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня есть `Label`, и я хочу что бы он не мгновенно, а плавно появлялся.
Пытался:

```
label1.Visible = 0.1;
label1.Visible = 0.2;
label1.Visible = 0.3;
label1.Visible = 0.4;
label1.Visible = 0.5;
label1.Visible = 0.6;
label1.Visible = 0.7;
label1.Visible = 0.8;
label1.Visible = 0.9;
label1.Visible = 1;
```

Но видимо такого в winforms не существует, поэтому нужен другой способ.

Comment: Оффтопик: а почему C++/CLI? Это ж жутко неудобный язык. А так, у WPF в комплекте есть анимации

Comment: Потому что другого то нету

Comment: @VerNick, что значит «нету»?

Comment: Я хочу именно на c++ написать.

Comment: А как сейчас он у вас появляется? Покажите код

Comment: Ну как как, `label1->Visible = True`

Comment: (обращайтесь через @, иначе я не узнаю о вашем комментарии если не зайду в топик намеренно) А вы как хотите? Чтобы он сбоку вылетал? Или плавно увеличивал прозрачность с полностью прозрачного до полностью непрозрачного? Или, может, чтоб размеры плавно увеличивал от 0 до нужных?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Плавно увеличивал прозрачность, об этом же у меня и вопрос

Comment: @АндрейNOP Сорян, по привычке думал что wpf, это clr.

Comment: Что еще за clr? :) У вас WinForms, судя по всему. Поправил вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейNOP  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxS1S.png Вот такой вот clr.

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

Comment: Ну, в любом случае, я вижу у вас в зависимостях `System.Windows.Forms`, ваш Label из этого же пространства имен? Значит платформа WinForms

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну ладно :), а про анимацию там что то знаете?

Comment: 1. Приложение с GUI на C++/CLI - зло. 2. WinForms практически не умеет в прозрачность. 3. Сделать анимацию можно с таймером или используя другой поток, но на C++/CLI для этого нужна куча кода, поэтому всем лень его писать (переходите на C#, там это реализуется в пару строк). 4. Можно найти готовую библиотеку для анимаций в WinForms (есть такие, я использовал), но я их вам советовать не буду, потому что см. пункт первый.

Comment: Ещё раз повторю: WinForms не может менять прозрачность контролов. Но вы можете попытаться сделать плавное выезжание (хинт: используйте другой поток или таймер).

Comment: Где ваш код? Покажите ваши попытки решения. / Повторю в третий раз: в WinForms не получится сделать плавное изменение прозрачности (во всяком случае, игра не стоит свеч). / Как использовать другой поток или таймер, смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829889/184217). / Библиотека для анимаций [Dotnet Transitions](https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions).

Comment: Так вы покажете собственную попытку решения? Покажите хоть что-то, и я дам вам работающий ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто меняй цвет. Сначала поставь совпадающий с цветом фона, затем доведи до чёрного. Используй `await Task.Delay(17);` чтобы сделать задержку между изменениями цвета и дать форме отрисоваться.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Идея менять цвет хороша. Вот только в C++/CLI нет async/await.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, тогда через таймер.