# Почему все советуют использовать c#, а не c++/cli?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Почему все советуют использовать c#, а в c++/cli не хотят? Я пробовал c++/cli, вроде нормальный язык. Спрашиваю про него, и все говорят что не надо мне на нем программировать. Почему так?

Comment: Смените круг общения, и вам начнут советовать другое

Comment: @Kromster всмысле?

Comment: Да хоть winapi используй

Comment: В смысле, что если вы смените круг общения на веб-разработчиков, то все начнут резко советовать JavaScript, а если пойдете в тусовку геймдевелоперов, то там как повезет - Юнити/C# или UE/C++. То есть инструмент зависит от задач. Какие задачи вы решаете - тот инструмент для них и берите.

Comment: @Kromster да я обычное приложение делаю

Comment: Все приложения обычные, какое вот есть приложение, чтоб прям ну необычное?

Comment: Язык программирования - инструмент всего лишь. Когда Вам нужно забить гвоздь, надеюсь, Вы молотком пользуетесь. Впрочем, гвозди заколачивать и отвёрткой можно, смекаете? ^_^

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну не знаю, особенное какое-нибудь, крутое)

Comment: @nobody Смекаю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте начистоту. Вы где-то когда-то прочитали, что язык C++ невероятно крут и на нём можно сделать почти что угодно (да, это так). Поэтому вы решили его учить. Попробовав консольные программки на C++, вам захотелось сделать приложение с графическим интерфейсом. К сожалению, вы начали с Visual Studio. Попробовали WinAPI - сложно и непонятно. И тут обнаружили шаблон Windows Forms. О, контролы можно перетаскивать на форму мышкой - очень легко создавать GUI. Так вы и познакомились (и я, и многие другие) с C++/CLI.

Так почему не продолжать использовать его? Потому что C# более совершенный язык: он проще, логичнее, продуманнее. Он постоянно развивается, в то время как C++/CLI нет. То, что в C# реализуется одной-двумя строками кода, в C++/CLI зачастую потребует десятков строк.

C++/CLI предназначен, фактически, для одной цели: служить "клеем" для связки *управляемого* (managed, .NET) и *неуправляемого* (нативного) кода. Например, у вас есть высокопроизводительная библиотека, сделанная на нативном языке типа C/C++/Delphi и т. п. И вы хотите создать десктопное приложение, использующее её. На C# можно легко, быстро и просто сделать работу с СУБД, файловой системой, сетью, разными форматами данных (xml, json), GUI и многое другое. Реализация всего этого на C++ займёт гораздо больше времени и труда. Но как теперь подключить ту самую библиотеку? Вот для этого и используется C++/CLI: на нём пишется обвязочный код (wrapper), который переадресует вызовы управляемого кода в неуправляемый. Всё! Этот язык используется (следует использовать) только для этого!

Подтверждением того, что язык C++/CLI не развивается (и его практически не используют) является количество книг (околонулевое), статей, вопросов-ответов на форумах. Вот вы задавали [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/868419/184217). Ответ на него так и не получили. Потому что на C++/CLI для реализации нужна куча кода, в то время как на C# - всего несколько.

Посмотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829889/184217). Оцените, сколько усилий (кода) нужно для реализации простой фичи на C++/CLI и сравните с лаконичностью и понятностью C#.